# How extract the current sentence and surrounding sentences around a particular word with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

Is there a way to get the surrounding sentences around any selected word in the sentence. Let's say our goal is to get the current sentence that contains the word "Champion" in your example below as well as the previous and next sentences that surround it regardless of their position,  tag or how many times the word champion is repeated.

```
text = "This is sentence 1. We are the champions. This is sentence 3. This is sentence 4. This is sentence 5. You are champions too."
```

In example above the word champion is repeated in sentence 2 and 6. So we want to get sent 1,2,3,5,6 and exclude sent 4.

How can we achieve this with Spacy or other tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this function will give the surrounding sentences.

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def surrounding_sentences(text, word):

    sentences=sent_tokenize(text)
    
    my_sents=[]
    for i in range(len(sentences)):
        if word in word_tokenize(sentences[i].lower()): 
            if i-1>0 : 
                previous_sent = sentences[i-1]
                my_sents.append(previous_sent)
            else: pass
            sent= sentences[i]
            my_sents.append(sent)
            if i+1 < len(sentences):
                nextsent = sentences[i+1]
                my_sents.append(nextsent)
            else: pass
    my_sents = list(set(my_sents))
    return my_sents
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `re.split` to split on punctuation, determine which sentences contain the word, and then grab anything with an index matching or adjacent to such a sentence.

```
>>> import re    
>>> text = "This is sentence 1. We are the champions. This is sentence 3. This is sentence 4. This is sentence 5. You are champions too."
>>> sentences = sentences = re.split('[\.\!\?] *',text)[:-1]
>>> sentences
['This is sentence 1', 'We are the champions', 'This is sentence 3', 'This is sentence 4', 'This is sentence 5', 'You are champions too']
>>> champion_indices = set(
    [
      i for i in range(len(sentences))
      if 'champions' in sentences[i].casefold()]
    )
>>> champion_indices
{1, 5}
>>> champion_adjacent_sentences = [
      sentences[i] for i in range(len(sentences))
      if (i - 1 in champion_indices
         or i in champion_indices
         or i+1 in champion_indices)]
>>> champion_adjacent_sentences
['This is sentence 1', 'We are the champions', 'This is sentence 3', 'This is sentence 5', 'You are champions too']
```

The only thing maybe unfamiliar here is the use of `casefold`, which is a fancier way of doing the trick where you lowercase two strings in order to do a case-insensitive comparison of them.